# rgbdslam provides transform from /map to /camera_link... what happens in localization?

Tags: slam, navigation, mapping, octomap, frame-id

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am looking at the frames that tf is providing. In rgbdslam, it is shown that `/camera_link -> /map`, which is ambiguous.  I understand that `/map` is what octomap_server is listening on. However, I have another node up and running that contains the transform `/map -> /odom -> /base_link -> /camera_link` , which is the suggested transform given by REP105. How do I reconcile the differences? or are these are conflicting transforms that I should run separately (I.e. obtain octomap via rgbdslam first)?

Sidenote: I see that rgbdslam's fixed frame is `/map`. Is there a switcheroo that I can change to so that the differences are reconciled?

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/182837/rgbdslam-provides-transform-from-/map-to-/camera_link...-what-happens-in-localization?/) by [xuningy](https://answers.ros.org/users/18591/xuningy/) on ROS Answers with karma: 101 on 2014-07-03

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The estimates of the different transformation from `/map` to `/camera_link` belong to different systems (RGBDSLAM and something else). Therefore I suggest using a different name for RGBDSLAM's `/map` frame. You can change the name by setting the parameter "config/fixed_frame_name" in RGBDSLAM's launch file.

There are ways to combine the two estimates, but to make it sound, you would need the uncertainty (covariance) for the respective transformations, which are not provided (at least RGBDSLAM doesn't do that). Otherwise you could just interpolate them with manually tuned weights.

---

Originally posted by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) with karma: 6468 on 2014-08-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0